# Sentiment Analysis with Logistic regression using sklearn

Tags: pandas, logistic-regression, sklearn-pandas, countvectorizer

I am trying to do sentiment analysis with sklearn.
Following is my code-

```
products=pd.read_csv("amazon_baby.csv")
products.head(3)

           name                                    review                                  rating
0   Planetwise Flannel Wipes    These flannel wipes are OK, but in my opinion ...           3
1   Planetwise Wipe Pouch   it came early and was not disappointed. i love...               5
2   Annas Dream Full Quilt with 2 Shams Very soft and comfortable and warmer than it l...   5

import string 
def remove_punctuation(text):
     try:
         text = text.translate(None, string.punctuation) 
     except: 
         translator = str(text).maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
         text = str(text).translate(translator)
     return text

review_without_punctuation = products['review'].apply(remove_punctuation)

products["review_without_punctuation"] = products['review'].str.replace('[^\w\s]','')
products.dropna(inplace=True)
products['sentiment'] = products['rating'].apply(lambda rating : +1 if rating > 3 else -1)
y=products['sentiment']
X=products['review_without_punctuation']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)

count_Vect = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')
train_data_vectorizer = count_Vect.fit_transform(X_train)
logisticRegr = LogisticRegression()
sentiment_model=logisticRegr.fit(train_data_vectorizer,y_train)

sample_test_data = X_test[10:13]
sample_test_data
87850    My daughter loves this The quality is great an...
8765     I have a home daycare and I LOVE this monitor ...
66497    Unique reasons why you should consider this be...
Name: review_without_punctuation, dtype: object
```

Trying to predict using trained model-

```
sample_test_data=count_Vect.fit_transform(sample_test_data)
sentiment_model.predict(sample_test_data)
```

Getting following error-

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
ValueError: X has 73 features per sample; expecting 131364
```

I know the problem that I am using vectorizer on entire X_test and trying to predict with that.
So how can I vectorize and train model in other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with small modification in code-

```
count_Vect = CountVectorizer().fit(X_train)
X_train_vectorized=count_Vect.transform(X_train)
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X_train_vectorized,y_train)
predictions=model.predict(count_Vect.transform(X_train))
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the error is due to not vectorizing the test data properly with respect to the train data. The flow should be something like this- train data should be fit and transformed while test data should be transformed (not fit) with respect to the train daata. Everything looks fine except the vectorzation of test data. Just transform the test data (no fit) with respect to the train data. Refer to the below code and let me know if this was what you looking for.

```
sample_test_data = count_Vect.transform(sample_test_data)  # just transform
sentiment_model.predict(sample_test_data)
```